# How to solve this strange bug? (c++)

Tags: c++

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
int main()
{ 
  std::string human = "";
  std::vector <char> translate;
  std::cout << "Enter English words or sentences to tranlate it into Whale's language.\n";
  std::cin >> human;
  for (int a = 0; a < human.size(); a++){
      if (human[a] == 'a' || human[a] == 'i' || human[a] == 'o' || human[a] == '.' || human[a] == ',' || human[a] == '?' || human[a] == '!' || human[a] == ' '
       || human[a] == 'A' || human[a] == 'I' || human[a] == 'O' || human[a] == '-'){
      translate.push_back(human[a]);}
      if (human[a] == 'e' || human[a] == 'u' || human[a] == 'E' || human[a] == 'U'){
          translate.push_back(human[a]);
          translate.push_back(human[a]);}}
  for (int b = 0; b < translate.size(); b++){
      std::cout << translate[b];}
}
```

The program above is about to translate words into other words. There are two rules for the translation:

1. Remove all the characters, except 'a', 'i', 'o', 'e', 'u'.
2. Just double the occurrence of 'e' and 'u'.

E.g. if I type "Hello world.",it should output "eeo o."

But the question is, my code does not work like that, it just output "eeo", which is odd I think. Can someone explain why?

Comment: you should print the user input to see if it really is what you think it is, or use a debugger to inspect the value

Comment: Why use `std::vector<char>` for the transformed result? A `std::string` would provide you equivalent functionality without requiring you to use a loop for printing the transformation result.

Comment: Also you could consider using a `switch` here: `for (auto const c : human) { if(std::isalpha(c)) { switch(c){ case 'a': case 'i': case ...: translate.push_back(c); break; case 'e': case 'u': case ...: translate.push_back(c); translate.push_back(c); break;  } } else { translate.push_back(c);} }`

Comment: Woww, I didn't know that, I thought only vectors and arrays can do it, anyway, thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Think of a `std::string` as a special purpose `std::vector`, that has a lot of additional domain specific functionality and optimizations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading from an `ifstream` into a string will break on whitespaces, hence `cin >> human` only reads what's effectively the first word.

Change this:

```
std::cin >> human;
```

To this:

```
std::getline(cin, human);
```

While we're here, let's cleanup the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <string>

int main()
{ 
  std::string human;
  std::string translate;

  std::unordered_set<char> keepers = {'a','i', 'o', 'A','I','O'};
  std::unordered_set<char> doublers = {'e', 'u', 'E', 'U'};

  std::cout << "Enter English words or sentences to translate it into Whale's language.\n";

  std::getline(cin, human);

  for (char c : human) {
      if (keepers.find(c) != keepers.end() || ::ispunct(c) || ::isspace(c)) {
          translate += c;
      }
      else if (doublers.find(c) != doublers.end()) {
          translate += c;
          translate += c;
      }
  }
  std::cout << translate << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: You could reduce the verbosity of the code a bit by replacing e.g. `keepers.find(c) != keepers.end()` with `keepers.count(c) == 1`. Furthermore depending on the exact requirements of the task it could be preferrable to replace `::ispunct(c) || ::isspace(c)` with `!std::isalpha(c)`. Since you're mentioning the includes, you should be adding `#include <cctypes>` for the char type functions.